# simply Store checkbox state to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-sqlite

I'm simply trying to store the state of checkbox in database but my application crashes when i click on submit button.I am trying to do this with a sqliteOpenHelper. After storing the state I also want to display it but first I'm not able to store it. Please guide me as I'm new to android. Here's my code..

**MainActivity.java**

```
    CheckBox ch1;
    Button btnSubmit;
    int checked=0;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ch1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    btnSubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    AddData();
    }

    public void AddData() {
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
      CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
         boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        checked = 1;
                    }else{
                        checked = 0;
                    }
                }
            });


            boolean insertData = dbhelper.addData(checked);

            if (insertData == true) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Order Placed!", 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong : 
      (.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**databasehelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "check.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COL1 = "SIZE";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(SIZE INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
   {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
   }

   public boolean addData(int s1){
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       contentValues.put(COL1, s1);

       long result  = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

       if(result == -1){
           return false;
       }else{
           return true;
       }
   }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-28 19:06:06.236 3806-3806/com.example.hp.checkbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.hp.checkbox, PID: 3806 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'booleancom.example.hp.checkbox.DatabaseHelper.addData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.hp.checkbox.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: 05-28 19:06:06.236 3806-3806/com.example.hp.checkbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.hp.checkbox, PID: 3806 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'booleancom.example.hp.checkbox.DatabaseHelper.addData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.example.hp.checkbox.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't put the event listener of the checkbox inside the submit button onClick listener.

Comment: try moving it out.

Comment: I tried removing it out and checking if the variable checked is 1 then a string has value otherwise it does not have any value and changed the datatype of column to string but still not worling

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues I'd suggest trying to use the following code , which separates the listeners rather than enclosing them (the checkChanged will only be applied if the submit button is clicked which is too late as it will be in whatever state it is (until you then change the checkbox)).

- Expecting, ***"but how do I know that it's added a row?"*** a method logData has been added to the **DatabaseHelper** which will list the rows in the log (e.g. an introduction to getting data from the database).

  #### MainActivity :-

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  CheckBox ch1;
  Button btnSubmit;
  int checked=0;
  DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<< ADDED

      ch1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
      btnSubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      // Button onClick Listener
      btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              dbhelper.addData(checked);
              dbhelper.logData(); //<<<< ADDED to display data to log (see logData in DatabaseHelper)
          }
      });

      // CheckBox onchanged Listener
      ch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
              checked = 0;
              if (isChecked) {
                  checked = 1;
              }
          }
      });
      //AddData(); //REMOVED
  }
  ```

### DatabaseHelper.java :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "check.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COL1 = "SIZE";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(SIZE INTEGER)";
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL1 + " INTEGER)"; //<<<< Suggestion
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        //db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); //<<<< INVALID
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); //<<<< ADDED CORRECTION
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(int s1){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, s1);

        //<<<< simplified return
        return (db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) > 0);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< New method to write contents to the log >>>>>>>>>>
    public void logData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr =  db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null, null,null, null);
        Log.d(
                "ENTRY TABLE INFO",
                "Number of rows in table is " +
                        csr.getCount() +
                        "; they are :-"
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "ENTRY TABLE INFO",
                    "Row # " +
                            String.valueOf(csr.getPosition()) +
                            " that has a value of " +
                            csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL1))
            );
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

#### Testing Results

After doing the following :-

1. Clicking the submit button (checkbox not checked).
2. Checking the checkbox.
3. Clicking the  submit button (checkbox checked).

The resultant output in the log is :-

```
05-28 21:47:40.628 1156-1156/ci.checkit D/ENTRY TABLE INFO: Number of rows in table is 2; they are :-
    Row # 0 that has a value of 0
    Row # 1 that has a value of 1
```